ACL2 Prove that the product of two positive numbers is positive
Here's a trivial book that proves that addition and multiplication of positive integers are positive.
Interestingly, ACL2 can also prove out of the box that x + y is positive when x and y are positive without first restricting x and y to the integers.
It can't do the same for multiplication however.
(in-package "ACL2-TRIVIAL")

(defun positivep (x)
  "holds iff x > 0"
  (< 0 x))

(defun positive-integer-p (x)
  "holds iff x > 0 and x is an integer"
  (and (positivep x) (integerp x)))

(defthm addition-of-positive-integers
  (implies (and (positive-integer-p x) (positive-integer-p y))
    (positive-integer-p (+ x y))))

(defthm multiplication-of-positive-integers
  (implies (and (positive-integer-p x) (positive-integer-p y))
    (positive-integer-p (* x y))))

(defthm addition-of-positive-numbers
  (implies (and (positivep x) (positivep y))
    (positivep (+ x y))))

;; This theorem is true, but fails with the error included at the end of this question.
;;
;; (defthm multiplication-of-positive-numbers
;;   (implies (and (positivep x) (positivep y))
;;     (positivep (* x y))))

I'm wondering why ACL2 can't conclude that multiplication of positive numbers is positive (if there's a deep reason) and how to convince ACL2 that it's true.
Goal'

([ A key checkpoint:

Goal'
(IMPLIES (AND (< 0 X) (< 0 Y))
         (< 0 (* X Y)))

*1 (Goal') is pushed for proof by induction.

])

No induction schemes are suggested by *1.  Consequently, the proof
attempt has failed.

Summary
Form:  ( DEFTHM MULTIPLICATION-OF-POSITIVE-NUMBERS ...)
Rules: ((:DEFINITION POSITIVEP))
Warnings:  Subsume and Non-rec
Time:  0.01 seconds (prove: 0.00, print: 0.01, other: 0.00)
Prover steps counted:  120

---
The key checkpoint goal, below, may help you to debug this failure.
See :DOC failure and see :DOC set-checkpoint-summary-limit.
---

*** Key checkpoint at the top level: ***

Goal'
(IMPLIES (AND (< 0 X) (< 0 Y))
         (< 0 (* X Y)))

ACL2 Error [Failure] in ( DEFTHM MULTIPLICATION-OF-POSITIVE-NUMBERS
...):  See :DOC failure.

******** FAILED ********

ACL2 Warning in CERTIFY-BOOK:  The attempted CERTIFY-BOOK has failed
while trying to establish the admissibility of one of the (local or
non-local) forms in the book to be certified.


Summary
Form:  (CERTIFY-BOOK "trivial" ...)
Rules: NIL
Warnings:  Subsume and Non-rec
Time:  0.02 seconds (prove: 0.00, print: 0.01, other: 0.01)
Prover steps counted:  350

ACL2 Error [Failure] in (CERTIFY-BOOK "trivial" ...):  See :DOC failure.
```


Because it's not true, you can prove
(thm (< 0 (complex 0 1)))

and I suppose this is just the way ordering is defined for complex numbers.
You would need your theorem to be something like
(thm (IMPLIES (AND (rationalp x) (rationalp y) (< 0 X) (< 0 Y))
         (< 0 (* X Y))))


Hmm. Interesting, so we have $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ as the top of the numerical tower unless we're working in ACL2(r).

yep https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Emoore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/?topic=ACL2____ACL2-NUMBERP
